# Xcode won't step over crash

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, debugging, xcode5

So, this has happened a number of times in a number of different projects.  I'll be debugging my app in Xcode, when Xcode breaks on an error.  After looking at it, I'd hit Step Over or Continue...and it wouldn't do anything.  More accurately, it acted like it stepped, but didn't actually go anywhere.  This can be repeated indefinitely, as far as I can tell.  One reason this is problematic is that it never gives me the crash log, because it never finishes crashing.  I only get the crash log when the app crashes and it isn't being debugged (which means I have to get it through Crittercism or by checking the device logs).

Anybody see this before, and/or know why it does this?  I haven't seen any mention of this elsewhere, but it's happened to me in several projects.

For example, in one project we use SocketRocket, and every once in a while (for an as-of-yet unknown reason) it crashes in SRWebSocket.m in the following method:

```
- (void)main;
{
    @autoreleasepool {
        _runLoop = [NSRunLoop currentRunLoop];
        dispatch_group_leave(_waitGroup);

        NSTimer *timer = [[NSTimer alloc] initWithFireDate:[NSDate distantFuture] interval:0.0 target:nil selector:nil userInfo:nil repeats:NO];
        [_runLoop addTimer:timer forMode:NSDefaultRunLoopMode];

        int i = 0;

        while ([_runLoop runMode:NSDefaultRunLoopMode beforeDate:[NSDate distantFuture]]) {
            NSLog(@"_runLoop %i %@", i++, [NSDate date]);
        }
        assert(NO);
    }
}
```

It crashes on the `while` line.  (I added the NSLog line, by the way).  When I hit Continue or Step Over, the line indicator flickers briefly, then appears again on the same line.  Note that it does not continue to the NSLog line, and nothing is written to the console at all.  I'm currently still trying to get it to crash again (this particular crash is rather unpredictable), but if I remember correctly, the line indicator says `EXC_BAD_ACCESS`, probably a prematurely deallocated object.

Comment: Are you sure there isn't something you're missing? Something written to the console perhaps?

Comment: @ThomasW Nope, that's the problem - nothing gets written to the console, it doesn't finish crashing, it just breaks there and won't go any farther.

Comment: It's not stopping on a breakpoint either? Perhaps you have a breakpoint set on exceptions?

Comment: @ThomasW I don't believe I do, and even if I did, I should still be able to step past them, right?

Comment: Have you ever figured the reason for the SRWebSocket crash on the while loop? Getting that crash as well...

Comment: @JPHribovsek I'm afraid not.  At some point I made a change that apparently made it crash in different places, sometimes, but I wasn't able to pinpoint the actual cause.  My best guess is still that something (maybe one of the opened streams?) wasn't properly closed or something.  Sorry.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An ObjC out of range error will result in throw an ObjC exception, which ends up - if uncaught - in an abort.  An abort really just raises a BSD signal (SIGKILL).  That's easy for the debugger to pass on to the process so it can die naturally from it.

EXC_BAD_ACCESS and EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION are funny exceptions, since they first come in on the Mach side of the OS.  To be properly propagated, they should be handled natively as Mach exceptions if there is a handler for them and if not, they should be passed to some system Handler, that turns them into the equivalent BSD exception (SIGSEGV) which will then be passed to the BSD signal handler and that will eventually cause your program to exit.

There's a long-standing bug in the kernel interfaces afforded to the debugger that makes it impossible for the debugger to properly effect this little dance from the outside.  So if you get an EXC_BAD_ACCESS, you're pretty much stuck there.  For the most part, that doesn't much matter, your program was just going to turn around and die anyway.  You wouldn't really gain any insight into your crash by watching it do that.

It only matters if you have installed, and want to debug, a SIGSEGV handler.  That has been hard on MacOS X for a decade or more.  Fortunately, only a very few people actually need to do this...

Comment: Thanks; this sounds like a reasonable explanation.  It would be convenient to have a logged stack trace (etc.) like usual, though - any idea if you can force the exception to be logged?

Comment: Language based exceptions need special treatment because they don't cause the program to terminate till the exception has propagated out to the outermost handlers.  So the origin of the exception is lost.  That's not so much the case with EXC_BAD_ACCESS etc.  In that case, if your program is running in the debugger it will stop at the point of the exception, and you can use "bt" and other debugger commands to log the exception, since you will be stopped at the point of the exception.  Otherwise a crash log will be generated.

Answer (score 3):

You're missing the point of Step Over. When you step over a line, you're saying execute the current line and go to the next visible one, regardless off whether the current line calls another procedure.

If the code crashes at any point, you will not be able to continue executing lines of code.

Comment: I know.  But I believe it _is_ supposed to finish crashing and give me the stack trace, etc. - I remember that it's done that for other crashes.  However, sometimes it just gets stuck on that line, instead.

Comment: Can you add to your question the affected lines and any messages you do get? Without that, it's hard to say specifically what's happening.

Comment: So you say "`EXC_BAD_ACCESS`, probably a prematurely deallocated object." That's your error, and the cause. Again, once a crash occurs, nothing else will be executed.

Comment: Please consider that `NSArray *a = [[NSArray alloc] init]; [a objectAtIndex:5];`, when run, actually crashes and logs the expected stack trace.  When I hit continue, the program does continue: it finishes crashing, and terminates.  Contrast that with `int *b = NULL; NSLog(@"b %i", *b);` which, when run, breaks on the second statement, does not log a stack trace, and loops indefinitely on that statement no matter how often I press continue.  I understand that the program cannot continue normal execution after crashing, but I should be able to get a logged stack trace, at least.

Answer (score 0):

To add to the previous answers; when debugging and EXC_BAD_ACCESS it can sometimes help to "Enable Zombie Objects" in your scheme.  If you are accessing an object that has been deallocated zombie objects will tell you which object you shouldn't have tried to make a call on and the method you tried to call.